# Changing speed of console.log in loop

Tags: javascript

I want to slow down console.log in my loop

```
    // function update to actualize value
function update() {
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(data);

    var count=0;
    for (var i=data.length; i--;) {
    count+=data[i];
        if(count >= 1) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    };
}
```

For example, show one console.log immediatly, and then, each .5s 
How can we do that ?
(maybe with setTimeout() but I don't want start delay)

Comment: `setTimeout()` is pretty much your only choice. (Well that or `setInterval()`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a variable to store the time of the last console.log.  Next, update that variable each time you console.log a value.  Finally, add a check for the threshold.

```
var lastOutput = 0; // Setting this to 0 initially will ensure it runs immediately
var outputThreshold = 500; // in milliseconds

function update() {
   requestAnimationFrame(update);
   analyser.getByteFrequencyData(data);

   if (new Date().valueOf() - lastOutput > outputThreshold) {
      // threshold met, output and update
      var count=0;
      for (var i=data.length; i--;) {
         count+=data[i];
         if(count >= 1) {
            console.log(data);
         }
      };
      lastOutput = new Date().valueOf();
   }
}

update(); // fire first call to update, after that requestAnimationFrame() will handle future calls
```

Comment: yeah, great! It doing what I wanted,but isn't this a bad pratice in term of memory allocation ? (I don't know, it's the reason why I ask).

Comment: Nope, the only memory you're using is storing the epoch time of the last iteration, which is just an integer.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be to introduce a timeout before running the update again each time...

```
// function update to actualize value
function update() {
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(data);

    var count=0;

    for (var i=data.length; i--;) {
        count+=data[i];
        if(count >= 1) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    };

    requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        setTimeout(update, 5000);
    });
}
```

I used `setTimeout()`  in preference over `setInterval()` as doing it this way (as well as moving the call to the end of the function) will make sure everything is completed, before starting the 5 second pause.  It ensures there's no overlap, should the preceeding code take longer than 5 seconds.

Comment: I have a <audio>, and when I stopping the song, the update() still running ! (but with the code of Rob Brander it's working correctly), thanks anyway

Comment: That would be easily fixed with a global boolean flag.  I wouldn't do what he's suggested, personally, but obviously you pick which suits you best :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the time delay *inside* the `for` loop, you'd do this:

```
function update() {
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(data);

    var i = data.length - 1, count = 0;
    function logger() {
      count += data[i];
      if (count >= 1)
        console.log(data);
      if (i-- >= 0)
        setTimeout(logger, 500);
    }
    logger();
}
```

Now, things are going to be pretty messy because you're *also* using `requestAnimationFrame()` to schedule another iteration of the whole thing; that really won't make sense anymore. You'll probably want to have that wait until the logging process is done:

```
function update() {
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(data);

    var i = data.length - 1, count = 0;
    function logger() {
      count += data[i];
      if (count >= 1)
        console.log(data);
      if (i-- >= 0)
        setTimeout(logger, 500);
      else
        requestAnimationFrame(update);
    }
    logger();
}
```